# Undefined jQuery error on remote validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am validating a field remotely and I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.
jquery.validate.js:617 
n.extend.checkjquery.validate.js:423
n.extend.elementjquery.validate.js:271
n.extend.defaults.onfocusoutjquery.validate.js:366
ijquery.validate.js:1359  
(anonymous function)jquery-2.0.3.js:4676  
i.event.dispatchjquery-2.0.3.js:4360
i.event.add.y.handlejquery-2.0.3.js:4594
i.event.triggerjquery-2.0.3.js:4893  
i.event.simulatejquery-2.0.3.js:5009  
i.support.focusinBubbles.i.each.f
```

Here is my code:

```
 $("input[id$=txtCompanyName]").rules("add", {
                required: true,
                alphanumeric: true,
                remote: function() {
                    return {
                        url: "/Resources/wsResources.asmx/IsCompanyAvailable",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ company: $("input[id$=txtCompanyName]").val() }),
                        dataFilter: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            var msg = JSON.parse(data);
                            if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                                return msg.d;
                            else
                                return msg;
                        }
                    };
                },
                messages: {
                    required: "This field is required",
                    alphanumeric: "Company name is not in correct format",
                    remote: $.validator.format("{0} already exists")
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be making a mistake in the PHP (or your remote code). I was and I just worked it out.  If you are writing:

```
if(foo){echo true;}
else {echo false;}
```

Try writing:

```
if(foo){echo "true";}
else {echo "false";}
```

It worked for me.  Have a look at the response to your ajax call in the console to see what's actually being returned.

Answer (score 0):

- The `remote` method is already defined with a `function()` contained inside the plugin.  You would not define a new function in place of the expected object literal.  In other words, simply [follow the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) and list the options inside of the `remote` method.
- If you are going to apply the `.rules()` method to more than one element using the jQuery "ends with" selector, then you *must* enclose `.rules()` within a jQuery `.each()`.
- Make sure you are including [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js) when you're using the `alphanumeric` rule.
- Many of your options are the defaults and can be left out.  The `data` of the field is already sent by default.  The `dataType` is already `JSON`, etc.
- You would not write any code to handle the server response yourself.  The `remote` method is already programmed to capture & handle the server response.  Your server-side script simply needs to respond with a `true`, `false` or JSON string.
- You would not define a custom message for `remote` using the `{0}` parameter placeholder since there is no parameter.  If your server-side code returns a JSON string, the field is made invalid and that string automatically becomes the error message.  Otherwise, you can define a static message for `remote` within `messages`.
- We cannot see your HTML or your call to `.validate()`.  However, verify that you call `.validate()` once to initialize the plugin on your form; and the form already exists when you call `.validate()`.  You **must** also have a unique `name` attribute on every field element or the plugin will fail.

Again, please refer to [the documentation for `remote`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).

```
$("input[id$=txtCompanyName]").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        alphanumeric: true,
        remote: {
            url: "/Resources/wsResources.asmx/IsCompanyAvailable",
            type: "POST"
        },
        messages: {
            required: "This field is required",
            alphanumeric: "Company name is not in correct format"
        }
    });
});
```